# Implementing Genetic Algorithms in Python: Sorting a list using fitness

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, genetics

I need to sort a lists of organisms according to fitness. This is probably the easiest thing but I'm having trouble. Super amateur here.

This is my code:

```
import random as randint

pop_size = int(raw_input('Enter a population size:'))
length = int(raw_input('Enter an orgnaism length:'))

for i in range(pop_size):
    org = []
    for a in range(length):
        org.append(randint.randint(0,1))
    print org 
    fitness = sum(org)

print sorted(org, key=fitness)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

An explanation would be really helpful :)

Edit: This is Python 2.7.2

Comment: do you want a list of lists sorted by the sum of their values? In your code you are overwriting the org list multiple times and then only trying to print the list from the last iteration.

Comment: Yes, I need a list of lists sorted by their values

Comment: Check my answer to see if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't collecting the lists generated in each iteration through the population size:

```
import random as randint

pop_size = int(input('Enter a population size:'))
length = int(input('Enter an orgnaism length:'))

orgs = []
for i in range(pop_size):
    org = []
    for a in range(length):
        org.append(randint.randint(0,1))
    orgs.append(org)

print sorted(orgs, key=sum)
```

This can be a bit cleaner using a list comprehension:

```
import random as randint

pop_size = int(input('Enter a population size:'))
length = int(input('Enter an orgnaism length:'))

orgs = [[randint.randint(0,1) for a in range(length)] for i in range(pop_size)]

print sorted(orgs, key=sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

the `key` key word argument needs to be a function. So if you had a list of dicts you would use something like `fitness = lambda x: x['fitness']` to sort the dicts by the `fitness` key. Also, maybe it's just an error from copy/pasting, but you're redefining fitness every time you go through the loop.

Comment: Do I have to use dictionaries or can I use a list?

Comment: You can use a list of lists if you'd like. `list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])` Or really a list of anything, as long as you call the key to sort by with a callable function like this. Another example of a callable function(that wouldn't work here) is `datetime.now`.

Comment: org.sort(key=lambda fitness: fitness[1]) Like that?

Comment: Yes, like that. However, you'll probably encounter a `TypeError` still, so I would suggest extracting the lambda to a separate function.